# Search form with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I have this code which is used to search on my site. When you fill in your search word and press enter it will execute the command. However I want to only execute the search script when the user presses a button. I can't get it work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var input = $('[data-search-input]');
    input.on('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13 && input.val().length > 3) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = input.data('search-input') + '{{ config.system.param_sep }}' + input.val();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input class="zoekveld" type="text" placeholder="Zoeken..." value="{{ query }}" data-search-input="{{ base_url }}{{ config.plugins.simplesearch.route}}/query" />
```

As you can see I used javascript to make the Search by Enter click work. But I want it to be done with a button. I hope you guys can help me out on this one.

Comment: $(yourbutton).click(function(){}); [JQUERY DOCS](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

Try event on click of a button:

```
 <button id="yourbutton" class="zoekbutton">Zoek</button>
    $('#yourbutton').on('click',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var input = $('[data-search-input]');
         window.location.href = input.data('search-input') + '{{ config.system.param_sep }}' + input.val();

    });
```

Comment: So I have done this:
<button id="yourbutton" class="zoekbutton">Zoek</button>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var input = $('[data-search-input]');

    input.on('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13 && input.val().length > 3) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = input.data('search-input') + '{{ config.system.param_sep }}' + input.val();
        }
    });
});

$(yourbutton).click(function(){
   $('[data-search-input]').trigger('keypress');
});
</script>

Still no effect..

Comment: yourbutton was a variable, i have changed it to id

Comment: Still does not give any effect.. Any other solution?

Comment: I realy thank you for your help. But it still does not give me any effect

Comment: what effect are you expecting?